# How to calculate standard deviation between 2 dimensionals points

Tags: android, math

I have a list of locations(longitude,latitude) to which i would like to calculate the standard deviation but i'm clueless how to do it in two dimensions. any ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

The concept of a single standard deviation does not generalize well to two dimensions. You can take the standard deviation of each component separately and you get two standard deviations. Then you can combine these into a single number taking `sqrt(X^2 + Y^2)`. This gives you a measure of how far, on average, the points are from the center of the point cloud.

The concept of variance, which is the square of the standard deviation, can be generalized, and it becomes the [covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix).

Comment: Agree, but what about correcting for distortion from the projection? Are there any software libraries that can handle this?